# Create new line in file (php)

Tags: php, html, file, fwrite

How do i make it skip a line (like clicking the enter button) in the file that i am editing? Here is the code:

```
<?php
$fn="file.txt";
$file=fopen($fn, "a+");
$size=filesize($fn);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
$add=$_POST['addition'];
fwrite($file, $add);
fclose($file);}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="addition" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: unclear what you want.. but carrage return character is `'\n'`

Comment: in 'HTML'  it's  `<br>`

Comment: `\r\n` if I understood your Q!

Comment: please clarify you want to clear spaces or want to include spaces? bit unclear

Answer (score 1):

Use the constant `PHP_EOL`:

```
fwrite($file, PHP_EOL);
```

As long as you're using php 5.0.2 or above it will be available and append an appropriate EOL character.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` can be used to define new line.

**PHP**:

```
<?php
    $fn="file.txt";
    $file=fopen($fn, "a+");
    $size=filesize($fn);
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
        fwrite($file, "\n");
    }
    fclose($file);
?>
```

**HTML**:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

---

I've posted the answer but I recommend [Durandal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124754/create-new-line-in-file-php/22124946#22124820) to use constant `PHP_EOL`.